# MVC.NET Core Bootstrap-Modal forms with multi-parameters don't reach Post controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a web app using modal forms to confirm some of the actions my users (or admin) might be allowed to do. The modal form setup is taken from Microsoft's IdentitySampleApplication project and been incorporated for my project in mostly the same way with this one difference. I am using the generic modal forms. I am trying to allow a user to have multiple user roles on an application (while their sample presumes the user will only have one role.)

I am now working out the deletion of roles for this type multi-role scenario for maintenance. I should point out that all instances of code involving only one id work fine, it is this one instance with 2 ids that fails to pass through either of the ids I need at the controller.

The deletion of a user role requires the key of the user and the role.
My controller has a bit of code like the following to accept the ids and present a modal form, which works quite nicely.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DeleteUserRole( string userid, string roleid ){...}
```

The HttpPost portion looks something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteUserRole( string userid, string roleid, IFormCollection form ){...}
```

however, this second action never gets the ids that were passed to the modal forms get method.

In all methods that only have a single routing id, I have no issues. It is only this one method that vexes me. I call it from this link. Note the two asp-route variables and I suspect this is at the heart of my issue, but the get call is fine with this, it is the post that has no values:

```
<a id="deleteRoleModal" asp-action="DeleteUserRole"
 asp-route-userid="@item.userId" asp-route-roleid="@item.roleId"
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-action-role" 
 class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
```

where at the base of the form I have a modal form implementation it uses looking like this:

```
@await Html.Partial( "_Modal", new BootstrapModel { ID = "modal-action-role", AreaLabeledId = "modal-action-role-label", Size = ModalSize.Medium } )
```

My modal form looks much like the samples used in the IdentitySampleProject and is shown here, it was not altered in any meaningful way yet works fine with single parameter call backs:

```
@model string
@using MyModels

<form asp-action="DeleteUserRole" role="form">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @await Html.Partial( "_ModalHeader", new ModalHeader { Heading = "Delete User Role" } )

    <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
        Are you sure you want to delete user role @Model?
    </div>
    @await Html.Partial( "_ModalFooter", new ModalFooter { SubmitButtonText = "Delete" } )
</form>
```

I am looking for a direction to go to solve the issue. I am hoping that indeed the double route ids are my issue, but I can not seem to find anyone else doing something like this in samples.

The generated management page looks mostly like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>my company</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootswatch/spacelab/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/navTabs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/partner.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">
        <div class="slideContainer">
            <div class="slide"><img src="/image/Firm-small2.jpg" alt="Offices" class="headerImage" /></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="/image/InLibrary225.jpg" alt="Library" class="headerImage"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="/image/DSC_9999editSM.JPG" alt="Offices" class="headerImage" /></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="/image/DSC_9925edit2SM.JPG" alt="Computer Room" class="headerImage" /></div>
        </div>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                    <li class="navtext">
                        <label>-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Welcome: Webmaster &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="navtext">
                    <label>Your Proven Partner in Cartoon Drawing</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <div><img src="/image/headerLogo.gif" alt="my company Logo" class="logoImage" /></div>

        <nav id="menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-inverse">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <div id="menuGroupItem">
                        <a href="/Partners">Partners</a>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#partnerMenu"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                    </div>
                    <ul id="partnerMenu" class="nav collapse" role="menu" aria-labelledby="partnerMenu">
                        <li><a href="/Partners/PartnerBio/Eddy%20A%20Fish"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Eddy A Fish</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Partners/PartnerBio/Tom%20A%20Hawk%20III"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Tom A Hawk</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/App/OurServices">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Events/News">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Events/Events">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Events/Pubs">Publications</a></li>
                <li><a href="/App/FirmHistory">Firm History</a></li>
                <li><a href="/App/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/Auth">Manage Website</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Auth/Logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="affiliation">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="/image/WBE_color_rgb_UP25.jpg" alt="" class="affiliationImage" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul class="rightAlign">
                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                <li>my company</li>
                <li>16 main street</li>
                <li>anytown, pa 00000</li>
                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                <li>610.111.1111</li>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main" class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<form action="/Users/UserRole/a2c77901-4a74-49aa-9354-1fadc943c8c4" method="post"><input id="UserId" name="UserId" type="hidden" value="a2c77901-4a74-49aa-9354-1fadc943c8c4" /><input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="hidden" value="BioEditor" />            <h3>Add roles for user: <span class="text-success">BioEditor</span></h3>
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <table class="table table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <th>Role</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-check text-success"> </i>BioEditor</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a id="deleteRoleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-action-role" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="/Users/DeleteUserRole?userid=a2c77901-4a74-49aa-9354-1fadc943c8c4&amp;roleid=8b12b24d-5836-46eb-a7aa-0be1818a67f5">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-check text-success"> </i>PowerEditor</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a id="deleteRoleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-action-role" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="/Users/DeleteUserRole?userid=a2c77901-4a74-49aa-9354-1fadc943c8c4&amp;roleid=c4f3bdf8-b880-423c-8de3-1e51329da104">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-check text-success"> </i>Administrator</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a id="deleteRoleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-action-role" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="/Users/DeleteUserRole?userid=a2c77901-4a74-49aa-9354-1fadc943c8c4&amp;roleid=f1aafc1e-0527-4542-8f0e-fb1afeccac46">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="input-group form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ApplicationRoleId field is required." id="ApplicationRoleId" name="ApplicationRoleId">
                            <option>Please select</option>
                        <option value="8b12b24d-5836-46eb-a7aa-0be1818a67f5">BioEditor</option>
<option value="c4f3bdf8-b880-423c-8de3-1e51329da104">PowerEditor</option>
<option value="f1aafc1e-0527-4542-8f0e-fb1afeccac46">Administrator</option>
<option value="fe77274d-4b16-46a6-8177-a84faf198c9b">EventEditor</option>
</select>

                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-user"> </i> Add Selected Role </button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ApplicationRoleId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8KeASaIZMdBDjnZy_1CdaouczJ-zwxPaQp-N5OQ5bGWfYzVfpDz7_iC0VlJb_cRDkqucT-8ENFhsNPe9Rng1Mqrm9VQbYQoSQwerxj953ql4v7dABrW6pioEySOJN7qFXaalGYePyjHoB0QiKxfuvkvh938tJG4gVnh5D1JvLyNBBKlR4d25PcoJOJZTdN_Bxg" /></form>    </div>
</div>


<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modal-action-role-label" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-action-role" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse ">
            <ul>
                <li class="navbar-link">&copy; my company</li>
                <li class="navbar-link text-muted"><a id="disclaimerLink" href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/site.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for any direction you might be able to provide, Kent

Comment: Please add generated html of you model in question.

Comment: Edited in the generated html for the management page.

Comment: Thanks Ahmar. That was the path to the answer, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was exactly a nudge in the right direction to finding the issue, thanks Ahmar. What is going on, due to the 2 ids being passed back to the controller is that the data is wrapped up in a query string rather than as a real route {controller}{action}{id}.

The modal won't pass along the query string to the final so I changed the model and wrapped up the values in the modal form for the final deletion and it all worked.  Thanks for asking the right the question to get this answered.